# problem with finding the minimum index of an array in the shared memory

Tags: cuda

I need to find the minimum index among an array. its easy to do this using one thread but I want to reduce it using parallel threads.

I did it using one thread (if threadIDx.x == 1) ....... and its working fine. but doing this in parallel will increase the efficiency which im looking for.

I wrote this code and it looks logical to me. but when I'm debugging its not picking the minimum value at all !

Code:

```
#define MIN(x,y) ((x < y) ? x : y)
#define MIN_IDX(x,y, idx_x, idx_y) ((x < y) ? idx_x : idx_y)
....
....


__shared__ int costs[nt];
__shared__ int bstids[nt];

int myM = 9999999;
int mtMId;
for (int s = nt/2 ; s >= 1 ; s/=2) {
  if (threadIdx.x < s) {
    myM = MIN(costs[threadIdx.x], costs[threadIdx.x+s]);
    costs[threadIdx.x] = myM;

    mtMId = MIN_IDX(costs[threadIdx.x], costs[threadIdx.x+s],bstids[threadIdx.x], bstids[threadIdx.x+s]);
    bstids[threadIdx.x] =  mtMId;
    __syncthreads();

}
}
```

nt is the number of threads and its a power of 2

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but the problem may lay not even in the part of the code you showed us. And how did you debug it? E.g. did you start with a really small array size, say 4, and checked that your program does what you want it to do every step, that is the intermediate results are correct?

Comment: I used cuda-gdb to debug. with a size of 4 or even 8 it was working. when I increase it to 128 or more it doesnt.
Update : 

I just tried to move the __syncthreads(); to outside the if condition and it looks working.

Comment: You have a conditionally executed `__syncthreads` call in your code. That is technically illegal

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to move the     __syncthreads(); to outside the if condition and it looks working.